# Windows 8.1 Wireless Authentication WPA2-Enterprise

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1, wpa2

For the network at my University I have to set wireless authentication to WPA2-Enterprise using TKIP encryption.
Since Windows 8.1 doesn't seem to have the usual wireless settings, I tried doing it via cmd. 
I tried

```
wlan set profileparameter name="NETWORK_NAME" authentication="wpa2-enterprise"
```

and

```
wlan set profileparameter name="NETWORK_NAME" AuthMode="wpa2-enterprise"
```

which both didn't work (invalid value "WPA2-Enterprise" for command option authentication / AuthMode).

Anyone know the correct paramter to set the authentication mode accordingly?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try AuthMode="WPA2SK" ?
When it says syntax error, it probably shows you a list of allowed commands. Check that out!

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
netsh wlan set profileparameter name="NAME" authentication=WPA2 encryption=TKIP
```

If you type netsh wlan set profileparameter ?, the help that comes up lists the available values for the settings.

```
Usage: set profileparameter [name=]<string> [[interface=]<string>]
       [SSIDname=<string>] [ConnectionType=ESS|IBSS] [autoSwitch=yes|no]
       [ConnectionMode=auto|manual] [nonBroadcast=yes|no]
       [authentication=open|shared|WPA|WPA2|WPAPSK|WPA2PSK]
       [encryption=none|WEP|TKIP|AES] [keyType=networkKey|passphrase]
       [keyIndex=1-4] [keyMaterial=<string>] [PMKCacheMode=yes|no]
       [PMKCacheSize=1-255] [PMKCacheTTL=300-86400] [preAuthMode=yes|no]
       [preAuthThrottle=1-16 [FIPS=yes|no]
       [useOneX=yes|no] [authMode=machineOrUser|machineOnly|userOnly|guest]
       [ssoMode=preLogon|postLogon|none] [maxDelay=1-120]
       [allowDialog=yes|no] [userVLAN=yes|no]
       [heldPeriod=1-3600] [AuthPeriod=1-3600] [StartPeriod=1-3600]
       [maxStart=1-100] [maxAuthFailures=1-100] [cacheUserData = yes|no]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by right-clicking on the wireless network symbol in the taskbar -> Open Network and Sharing Center -> Set up a new connection or network.

Answer (score 0):

You can go try connecting to your wireless connection first (even though it wont connect), then open change adapters setting or network connections window, then double click on the "still connecting" wifi adapter -> click wireless properties next to details...